Max len error when using Huggingface model
I am getting the issue
lm = VLLM(
  File "/home/ubuntu/isolated_product_description/ipd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/langchain_core/load/serializable.py", line 120, in __init__
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/isolated_product_description/ipd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydantic/v1/main.py", line 341, in __init__
    raise validation_error
pydantic.v1.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for VLLM
__root__
  The model's max seq len (32768) is larger than the maximum number of tokens that can be stored in KV cache (32624). Try increasing `gpu_memory_utilization` or decreasing `max_model_len` when initializing the engine. (type=value_error)

when using this code. I have tried using max_model_len which is less than KV cache. Still getting the same issue.
from langchain_community.llms import VLLM
llm = VLLM(
                vllm_kwargs={"quantization": "awq"},
                max_model_len=30624,
                model=TheBloke/Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.2-AWQ,
                # gpu_memory_utilization=1.0,
                trust_remote_code=True,  # mandatory for hf models
                max_new_tokens=512,
                speculative_max_model_len = 30624,
                top_k=40,
                top_p=0.95,
                temperature=0.7,
                repetition_penalty= 1.1,
            )


This isn't working currently because max_model_len is not an attribute of the langchain VLLM class. Since max_model_len is a vllm.LLM property, the parameter is passed via vllm_kwargs. This is where the gpu_memory_utilization parameter also belongs in your example:
from langchain_community.llms import VLLM

llm = VLLM(
    model="TheBloke/Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.2-AWQ",
    trust_remote_code=True,
    # ...
    vllm_kwargs={
        "quantization": "awq",
        "max_model_len": 30624
        "gpu_memory_utilization": 0.9 # Default value
    }
)

Langchain's VLLM wrapper class handles some of the base  vllm.LLM.__init__ parameters, namely model, tensor_parallel_size, trust_remote_code, dtype and download_dir (relevant source code). The generation specific arguments are passed to vllm.SamplingParams. Any other vllm initialisation arguments should be passed through vllm_kwargs.
